# Setting up a wireless network in dorm room

Tags: wireless-networking

I recently got an internship and they put us in a dorm-like place. All the connections to the internet are hardwired through terminals in the wall. I have a linksys e1000 router and I want to set up a wireless connection. Is this possible? I know I can't simply connect one of the terminals to my router.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually try anything?  Without knowing the topology of the dorm's network it's impossible to answer.  That aside, there's a good chance you will NOT be allowed to do this.  You're best bet is to talk with campus IT for the rules.

Comment: Talk to them. Pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the University would allow you to do this - but what you could do as an alternative, is hook the router/AP up to a 2nd Ethernet port on your Desktop (if you have one, cheap enough to buy a PCI card), then setup ICS and share the Internet connection out to the AP, that ought to work, though it would need some configuring.